# Where is Photoshop's default temp file location on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop

I'm new to Windows 7 and would like to know where Photoshop's default temp file is. The reason is that I am lacking space on my local disk, and I would like to delete the large temp file that Photoshop created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found it. It's in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp`. To access that, you can type `%LocalAppData%\Temp` in the `Start` > `Run` field.